# How can I generate token using reportportal API

Tags: reportportal

I am looking for a way to generate token using login/password on reportportal. 
Pretty sure, there should be a way using a API call. I am just not able to find it.

So given, (project name, user, password), I should get a token that I can use for making other API calls.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Get API token

Before getting API token, you have to generate it.

If it's already generated (you have logged in with this user), this endpoint will return you existing API token:

`GET` `/sso/me/apitoken`

Example:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: bearer 4f73871b-e477-4f49-b1bd-805b24201fe0' 'http://web.demo.reportportal.io/uat/sso/me/apitoken'
```

Response:

```
{
  "access_token": "b1debc0a-d47d-492f-aa7c-3e2e0fb96332",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "scope": "api"
}
```

Pay attention, that bearer in 1st (curl) request has scope `UI` and bearer in response has scope `API`.

- **UI token** expires according to server config and TimeToLive for user session.
- **API token** has endless TTL

** If `GET` requests returns you error, then you need to generate token.

#### Generate API token

`POST` `sso/me/apitoken`

Example:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: bearer 4f73871b-e477-4f49-b1bd-805b24201fe0' 'http://web.demo.reportportal.io/uat/sso/me/apitoken?authenticated=true'
```

Response:

```
{
  "access_token": "4e76e31e-0250-4e5e-ba66-90105dd014bb",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "scope": "api"
}
```

(!) Tokens are public. Used from public account at demo instance http://web.demo.reportportal.io

[image]

Comment: This example requires a bearer token to get a bearer token.
The question is how to retrieve a bearer token (such as the user's UUID) via the API by providing a username/password.
In other words, how can this be done without a browser?

Comment: I'm curious how this answer was accepted, per the comment from Josiah, the ask is for how to do this with username/password and without a browser, i.e. python requests.get() with basic auth.  I'd like to know this as well, I am able to login with requests.get via #login; however, how to actually get the api token is another issue.

Answer (score 3):

Make a post to:

```
/uat/sso/oauth/token?grant_type=password&password=***password***&username=***username***
```

Set basic authentication with credentials (username: ui and password: uiman) to get the accesstoken for scope UI, use this token to fetch apitoken.